# Jquery mobile iteration issue and cannot move to next page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am new to Jquery.
Tried to authenticate from database and during authentication if the user is invalid it shows an alert message as user invalid and If its a invalid user I am getting 2 alert messages stating "Invalid user" and if its a valid statement I am getting 4 alert message as valid user.Is there any way to display only 1 alert box or stop the iteration,I fear "break" cannot be used in "if" statement and I tried using return statement and still I can see 2 alertbox showing invalid user if the user is invalid and 4 alert box if its valid box.

2nd problem is if its valid user It should move to next page and the window.location() is not working,if possible may I have the coding for it.Please help

**Here is the coding:**

```
    function loginRecord(){

     db.transaction(function(tx){
     var user=$('#username').val();
     var pwd=$('#pass').val();       
     var x="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='"+user+"' AND password='"+pwd+"' ";    
     tx.executeSql(x,[],function(tx,result){
     if (result.rows.length > 0){

     var msg="Hello " +user + "your password is " +pwd;
     alert(msg);

    window.location.href="page3.html";

  }
  else{

    alert("Invalid user!");

    return false;                   

}
});
});
}
```

Comment: Approach is wrong ... giving loads of alerts is not the way...try giving those information on the page itself and for the second query try window.location.href

Comment: Tried it and it does not work

Comment: what you have tried editit again please? let me c

Comment: also map your full message into a string and alert that string only

Comment: I have edited the question please check

Comment: Shouldn't it be **window.location.href = "page3.html";** and not **("page3.html")**?

Comment: np. did it fix the issue?

Comment: part of the issue @dwhite.me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"
Check again and comment

```
if (result.rows.length > 0){
        var msg= "Hello " +user + "your password is " +pwd;
        alert(msg);    
        window.location.href="page3.html";    
      }
      else{    
        alert("Invalid user!");    
        return false; 
          }
```

Comment: Thanks its going to next page and still getting 2 alert box " Hello user your password is password" and if its invalid user again there are still 2 alert box "invalid"..why am I getting 2 alert box instead of one

Comment: That must be in some other code...you have to update your whole code to let me see else i cant figure it out

Comment: You have been great so far and would be helpful if this issue is resolved

Comment: What is the message you are getting in those two alert boxes?

Comment: If its a valid user I am getting same alert message twice (Hello username your password is password) if its a invalid user its (Invalid user!) twice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58939/discussion-between-tushar-gupta-and-manikandan).

Answer (score 0):

Just now noticed that I have called the function twice and this has caused to 2 alert box,Thanks so much for your answer @ Tushar Gupta